# Texmaker PDF Viewer Toolbar Lost

Tags: texmaker

Trying to reorder the elements in the **PDF viewer toolbar** I dragged outside the window and **disappeared**. Then went to the view options making an attempt to take it back but marking PDF controls or not made no difference. Also I **tried resetting** the Texmaker configurations, **re-installing**, however **the problem remains**. Here's how I want the PDF viewer to look like [(Toolbar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2qWQ.png)
Running latest version of Texmaker for Pop OS! (Ubuntu-based distribution).

Answer (score 1):

- Not sure if I understand your English 100 % -- a screenshot of the complete screen would help.
- Maybe try `Options > Commands > Pdf Viewer > Select "Embed"`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Version 4.3.0 restore/activate internal pdf toolbar under:

`Options > Configure TeXstudio > Internal PDF Viewer > Check in "Auto-hide Toolbars in Embedded Mode"`

[image]